# xml schema in jaxb java not getting expected output

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, dhl

My expected output is in this format of JAXB.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<req:ShipmentRequest xmlns:req="http://www.dhl.com"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.dhl.com ship-val-global-req.xsd" schemaVersion="5.0">
<Request>
<ServiceHeader>
  <MessageTime>2001-12-17T09:30:47-05:00</MessageTime>
  <MessageReference>1234567890123456789012345678901</MessageReference>
  <SiteID>CustomerTest</SiteID>
  <Password>alkd89nBV</Password>
</ServiceHeader>

</req:ShipmentRequest>
```

but i am able to get only

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ShipmentRequest xmlns:req="http://www.dhl.com"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.dhl.com ship-val-global-req.xsd" schemaVersion="5.0">
<Request>
<ServiceHeader>
  <MessageTime>2001-12-17T09:30:47-05:00</MessageTime>
  <MessageReference>1234567890123456789012345678901</MessageReference>
  <SiteID>CustomerTest</SiteID>
  <Password>alkd89nBV</Password>
</ServiceHeader>

</ShipmentRequest>
```

how can i add a prefix like "req:" as shown in the expected output as i am using jaxb to marshall and unmarshall

Comment: For me this works with an annotation like `@XmlAttribute(name = "req:ShipmentRequest")`

Comment: thank you @IQV  yes i am  able to get the expexteced output but i am adding it in root element @XmlRootElement(name="req:ShipmentRequest")